# ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated,

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation, pca

I have two arrays with axis=0 (there are the result of the mean and the std of a df):

```
df_cats = 
0      58.609619
1     105.926514
2      76.706543
3      75.405762
4      68.937744
         ...    
75    113.124268
76    125.557373
77    130.514893
78    141.373779
79    109.185791
Length: 80, dtype: float64 0     63.540835
1     55.053429
2     96.221076
3     42.963771
4     57.447924
        ...    
75    42.080755
76    55.309517
77    38.997856
78    57.364695
79    40.197461
Length: 80, dtype: float64

df_dogs = 
0      86.870361
1     153.085205
2      89.576416
3     139.721924
4     107.218750
         ...    
75    129.498291
76    108.676025
77    113.125732
78    145.829346
79    100.272461
Length: 80, dtype: float64 0     57.699218
1     71.814790
2     40.130439
3     44.966932
4     48.964512
        ...    
75    50.994298
76    58.257198
77    89.240987
78    58.945353
79    68.841721
Length: 80, dtype: float64
```

And I'm trying to concatenate the two arrays with axis=1, using this code:

```
dogs_and_cats = np.concatenate((df_dogs, df_cats), axis=1)
```

but always have this problem:

```
**ValueError:** zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

How can i can concatenate that?

Comment: What exactly are `df_dogs` and `df_cats`?  What you show look more like dataframes or something else, not `numpy` arrays.  If they aren't arrays, `concatenate` will first do `temp=np.array(df_dogs)`.  Test that and tells us about `temp` (shape and dtype).

Comment: Are two arrays producto of this function: def standardize(x):
    #This function takes as input a numpy array and returns a stadardized numpy array of the same dimensions.
    #Sample input: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
    #Sample output: np.array([[-1,-1,-1],[1,1,1]])
    
    # Your code here:
    column_mean = np.mean(df, axis=0)
    column_std = np.std(df, axis=0)
    pixel_stand = column_mean/column_std
    print(pixel_stand).

Comment: I can't read code in a comment!  I don't care how they were created.  I want to know type etc of the actual variables that you are trying to concatenate.  You error in when trying `df_dogs.shape` suggests it is `None`, not an array or even a dataframe.

Comment: There are only two arrays with axis=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One dimensionnal arrays don't have a second dimension. This is where your problem comes from. You can concatenate by modifying the shape of these arrays to turn them into 2D arrays with only one column with the following code :

```
df_dogs.shape=(df_dogs.shape[0],1)
df_cats.shape=(df_cats.shape[0],1)
```

And now, you can concatenate your arrays.

Comment: I used that but i have this result: 

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-de7a892b7bb0> in <module>
      1 # Your code here:
----> 2 df_dogs.shape=(df_dogs.shape[0],1)
      3 df_cats.shape=(df_cats.shape[0],1)
      4 dogs_and_cats = np.concatenate((df_dogs, df_cats), axis=1)
      5 dogs_and_cats

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: You are not dealing with array I assume. These are still DataFrames. You can either turn them into arrays with numpy.array(...) or you can concatenate them as DataFrames using pd.concat([df_dogs,df_cats]).

Comment: I convert them in two arrays, no more df

Comment: Are they numpy arrays? They should have a shape attribute in that case.

Comment: when i look what shape have: **AttributeError**: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: Do the folowing line work? pd.concat([df_dogs,df_cats])

Comment: ValueError: All objects passed were None